# Что делать с утратившими актуальность данными в localstorage при обновлении версии приложения?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localstorage

Есть приложение на Vue.js, оно хранит свое состояние и пользовательские настройки в виде сериализованного объекта в localStorage примерно таким образом:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      config: {
                someKey1: "someValue",
                someKey2: "someValue2",
                somekey3: ["one", "two", "three"],
                //...
              },
      appname: "myApp",
    };
  },
    mounted() { //при загрузке
        let savedConfig = localStorage.getItem(this.appname . '_config');
        if (savedConfig !== null) {
            this.config = JSON.parse(savedConfig);
        }
    },
    updated() { //при изменении состояния
        let savingConfig = JSON.stringify(this.config);
        localStorage.setItem(this.appname . '_config', savingConfig);
    },
    //Проверки, валидации и весь не относящийся к вопросу код опущен
};
```

И это *работает*.

Но в случае мажорного обновления приложения (добавления/изменения логики и т.д.) объект `config` может сильно поменяется. Тогда лежащая у пользователя в браузере копия станет неактуальна.

Как грамотно заложить условие того, что поменялась версия приложения и как пересобрать в этом случае этот объект на клиенте в идеале с сохранением всех/большинства настроек сделанных пользователем? Есть ли какие-то устоявшиеся подходы по этому поводу?

Comment: не знаю на счёт устоявшихся подходов, но почему бы не написать функцию получения конфига из лс, и внутри неё в зависимости от конфига дополнять/изменять данные?

Comment: 1. Как сделано при установке нового пакета в Linux? Менеджер пакетов предлагает: использовать новый конфиг, оставить старый (на свой страх и риск), сравнить файлы, либо открыть редактор. Это максимально грамотно, но для вашего случая не подходит. 2. Можно сделать миграцию старого конфига в новый: на входе текущий протухший + новый шаблонный, на выходе объединенный. Плюс цепочка миграций v1 => v2, v2 => v3. Нужно обновить v1 => v3? Тогда применяем последовательно. А чтобы эта магия работала, пишите тесты. 3. `пользовательские настройки в виде сериализованного объекта` - безобразная реализация

Comment: @TotalPusher да именно 2 вариант я прокручиваю в голове, но думал вдруг есть более элегантные методы... А какую менее безобразную реализацию вы бы предложили при условии отсутствия бэкэнда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рассуждаю так:

- вначале необходимо продумать структуру конфигурации (модуль/аспект/домен/модель - есть разные названия для этого)
- предусмотреть версионирование
- localstorage - это key-value хранилище, запрос `WHERE domain="user" AND version="1.0.0"` написать нельзя. Нет типизации, значение всегда string
- если какая-то настройка переезжает из одного места в другое, нужна миграция
- нет смысла поддерживать 100 миграций, достаточно ~3 последних, кто не успел обновиться - получает дефолтный конфиг

Теперь как это можно сделать

### Структура

Допустим, нужно хранить данные о пользователе (user).

Получить имя пользователя можно так:

```
localStorage.getItem('v1:user:personal_data:name')
```

Тут есть версия (я для упрощения не стал делать семантическое версионирование `1.0.0.0-...`, просто `v1`), домен пользователь `user`, аспект/модель персональные данные `personal_data` и собственно имя.

Рекомендую хотя бы в общих чертах ознакомиться с концепцией DDD. Так можно заложить фундамент будущей конфигурации.

Со структурой разобрались, далее будем эволюционировать код.

### Фасад для localstorage

Писать `localStorage.getItem...` не удобно. Поэтому делаем фасад. Получится так:

`settings.get("user", "personal_data", "name")`. А может быть, используем dot notation: `user.personal_data.name`.

В фасаде будут гетеры и сетеры. Возможно, первый раз стоит получить вообще все свойства в объект, и работать уже с ним.

Как раз `JSON.parse` и `JSON.stringify`. Во Vue для этого подходит [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), он сюда очень хорошо вписывается, я бы использовал именно его.

> хранит свое состояние и пользовательские настройки в виде сериализованного объекта

Vuex имеет модули. Лучше разделить пользовательские настройки и состояния на различные модули Vuex. Может быть, тогда и версионирование не потребуется.

### Версионирование и миграция

Допустим, `name` в новом релизе `v2` теперь называется `firstName`.

В скрипте установлена переменная `releaseVersion = 'v2'`, а в localStorage `userVersion = 'v1'`.

Скрипт видит, что версия отличается, и выполняет миграцию:

```
let name = settings.get('v1:user:personal_data:name')
settings.set('v2:user:personal_data:firstName', name)
settings.remove('v1:user:personal_data:name')
// в конце делаем userVersion = releaseVersion
```

На этом этапе рекомендую использовать TDD (разработку через тесты). Первый тест должен проверять, что имя было перенесено.

После этого начинаем усложнять логику:

- если значения нет, используем какое-то дефолтное значение
- вместо простыней с названиями переменных - используем маппинг `"user:personal_data:name": "user:personal_data:firstName", ...`
- предусматриваем колбек, если простым маппингом нельзя перенести (например, делаем верхний регистр в имени)
- делаем цепочки миграций v1 => v2 => v3
- если вы дошли до этого этапа, у вас получилась магия

Без TDD реализовать это практически невозможно, запутаетесь и плюнете.

### PS

Также я посмотрел готовые JS-пакеты, но ничего подходящего не нашел.

Если у вас legacy-код, сделайте фасад, который будет работать как с legacy, так и с modern реализациями. Когда от legacy избавитесь, фасад можно грохнуть.